# Access Denied from jdbc to google cloudsql

Tags: java, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to cloudmysql gcp instance using jdbc connection string with ssl enabled. It gives me access denied for user. I followed the following steps

1. I got the client-key, client-cert, server-ca from cloudmysql instance.
2. Generated the truststore.jks by keytool from server-ca.pem.
3. Now below is the snippet. When running getting access denied for user.let me know if anything is missing

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;  
class JdbcTest{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","D://truststore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true", "username", "password");    
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SHOW DATABASES");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println("test");  
con.close();  
}catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}  
}  
}
```

Comment: Does it work without SSL?

Comment: Can you the share the exact error message you are receiving?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere: it works fine without ssl.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra: "access denied for user 'Test' using password yes" is the error

Comment: Turn on SSL Debug and share the output of SSL Debug.